# unit testing jsp 2.0 .tag files

Tags: unit-testing, jsp-tags

How do people test jsp 2.0 tags? The ones that have .tag extensions and are basically jsp files with some extra support for passing parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way we do this is by making a jsp page as a test fixture and running the asserts through selenium. Hardly a "quick" unit test, but not as inefficient as you could fear.

You want that selenium test-rig up an running anyway, right ? We use it both for some unit-test like fixtures and to run JsUnit tests in a systematic manner.

Comment: :( there should be a simpler way